# Centos8 image creation through packer on azure results in to errors

Tags: centos, packer

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here as I am unable to create the image? actually the commands, when I run on my host Centos machine, works fine but when I execute the same commands through packer result into error.

JSON file:

```
{
  "builders": [{
    "type": "azure-arm",
  
    "client_id": "{{user `azure-client-id`}}",
    "client_secret": "{{user `azure-client-secret`}}",
    "tenant_id": "{{user `azure-tenant-id`}}",
    "subscription_id": "{{user `azure-subscription-id`}}",
    
    "managed_image_resource_group_name": "{{user `azure-resource-group`}}",
    "managed_image_name": "CentOS8-Packer",
  
    "os_type": "Linux",
    "image_publisher": "OpenLogic",
    "image_offer": "CentOS",
    "image_sku": "8_2-gen2",

    "location": "{{user `azure-region`}}",
    "vm_size": "{{user `vm-size`}}"
  }],

  "provisioners": [
    {
      "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .Path }}'",
      "script":"ami-script.sh"
      "type": "shell"
    }
  ]
}
```

ami-script.sh content:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
dnf update -y
dnf install terminator xrdp -y
```

Error:
Updated part:

`dnf update -y` error:

[image]
[image]
dnf install terminator xrdp error (resolved)
[image]

Comment: Does your build environment have the `epel-release` repository enabled?  The `terminator` and `xrdp` packages do not seem to be available in the official release repositories for CentOS 8.  Maybe you need to add `dnf install epel-release -y` in `ami-script.sh` before attempting to install your packages?

Comment: @GracefulRestart Indeed the failure of terminator and xrdp was due to missing epel-release but the image creation is still failing due to ` dnf update -y ` command errors. How can i resolve this?

Comment: What errors do you get with `dnf update -y`?

Comment: @GracefulRestart `error: lsetfilecon: (/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI;5f48155c, system_u:object_r:boot_t:s0) Operation not supported`
Please look at images posted in question, the first and second one is showing `dnf update` error.

Comment: The pictures are difficult to read.  The error in your last comment would indicate that the process was unable to set the SELinux file context for `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI`.  This could be an indication that your `/boot` partition does not support SELinux contexts.  According to a comment on this [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1722766#c46) that may be related, those errors should not cause installation failure.